# How to get last item in drop down list in Selenium IDE and use it?

Tags: selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE and I have a dynamic drop down menu that i need select last item:

This is my code:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>document.getElementsByName(&quot;id&quot;)[0].length-1</td>
    <td>x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>selectd>name=id</td>
    <td>index={$x}</td>AndWait</td>
    <t
</tr>
```

Error display when i run script:
[error] Threw an exception: document.getElementsByName is not a function

If anyone has any suggestions that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: could you share the dropdown list?

Answer (score 0):

you could try using "mouse over" command with target of your drop-down and using "clickAt" with value of the last line(item) from the drop-down.

If this is exact copy of your code, you have an error below:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>document.getElementsByName(&quot;id&quot;)[0].length-1</td>
    <td>x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>selectd>name=id</td>
    <td>index={$x}</td>AndWait</td>
    <t                              <------- this isn't closed properly.
</tr>
```

I had suggested following:

```
mouseOver
id=xxx (or use Xpath)


clickAt
id=(selected item)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: give an example to make a better answer :)